# Clearing SQL Server 2005 event log

Tags: sql-server-2005, logs

I need to delete the SQL Server 2005 logs, but can't figure out how to do it. I'm talking about the logs that are found in `Management -> SQL Server Logs` in SSMS object explorer. I can't seem to detete them from there, so I assume there is another way or a command to do it.

Also, I noticed that at least some log entries can be found in Windows Event Log (the ones about failed logins, for example). Will those get deleted too if I find a way to clear the SQL Server logs? Or should I clear the event log separately?

I looked for an answer but people seem to ask mostly about clearing transaction logs which is not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log files in question are named `ERRORLOG`, `ERRORLOG1` etc. and are usually stored in LOG folder somewhere inside MSSQL installation directory. In the beginning of the log there is a message like this:

> Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'

It can help to determine the exact path.

If the need to delete these logs is caused by a security concern, it's good to execute `sp_cycle_errorlog` proc to make log cycle. This way the `ERRORLOG` file will be empty and all the events will be in `ERRORLOG1`, `ERRROLOG2` etc which can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Logging SQL Server messages in file', null, NULL, NULL, N'asc'
```

The text column will provide you with the current location of your SQL error log file namely `ERRORLOG`.

The currently used error log file cannot be deleted. You can cycle the log file using `sp_cycle_errorlog` and the delete the former file which will be named `ERRORLOG.1`.

The windows event logs will have to be cleared out separately.